# Why is ContentDialog and Prism Navigation blowing up my UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, prism

I am showing a content dialog on one of my sessionstateaware pages, I close the dialog fine and can reopen another on the same page as many times as I want. When I navigate away and come back and try to reopen my dialog, it blows up with this error:

> WinRT information: Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time.
>   Additional information: An async operation was not properly started.

I have tried numerous things, but it seems whenever I navigate away and come back, somehow the reference to the control is lost and another gets created?

Here is a little snippet of the problem area:

```
if(asyncCommand != null)
asyncCommand.Cancel();

var result = new ContentDialogResult();
if (CanOpenNewDialog)
{

    CanOpenNewDialog = false;
    MyContentDialog.Title = "Homebuyer Options - " + apt.Customer1FullName;
    asyncCommand = MyContentDialog.ShowAsync();

    result = await asyncCommand.AsTask();
}
```

Comment: Has nobody else ran into this? Open up a content dialog, navigate to a different page, come back and try to open a dialog and boom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I was navigating using prism, every time I came back to my page I resubscribed to my event that was creating a dialog. To fix this I simply call unsubscribe OnNavigatedFrom.

Comment: _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShowHomebuyerSelectionDialogEvent>().Unsubscribe(ShowHomebuyerSelectionDialog);

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue with ContentDialouge when navigating more than one time. App is just crashing by saying "An async operation was not properly started. Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time."

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this. For example the method Show Dialouge, where the ContentDialog is calling, should be awaited. So make the Show Dialouge method as a task.

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
   await ShowDialouge();
 }

 private async Task ShowDialouge()
  {
    ContentDialog dialouge = new ContentDialog();
    await dialouge.ShowAsync();
  }
```